# compiz shifter not present

Tags: compiz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to correctly enable Desktop Cube in Unity 3D](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86977/how-to-correctly-enable-desktop-cube-in-unity-3d)

Hey guys i am using ubuntu 11.10 and i have been using ubuntu for about 6 months now, i saw in a few videos about ubuntu and found out about some type of cube and it happened to be Compiz shifter which made that cube thing.
I have been searching for a loooooooong time and never found out how to install compiz shifter.
Please guys teach me how to install compiz shifter in my ubuntu.
(i dont have a graphic card)if i cant install it without a graphic card, shouldnt i be able to install it in another way?? 
Oh come on!! I would love to have that in my ubuntu.
(if i need to do some changes tell me cause i am a c++ programmer and i might be able to edit a few things)

Comment: The first thing to do is to determine if you are speaking of either:                                                          
                                                                 
a) shift switcher
b) desktop cube            
an example of the shift switcher: www.youtube.com/watch?v=PH3L_Ed2LRE
and if you think it is the Desktop Cube I would refer to this askubuntu.com/questions/83345/compiz-desktop-cube-problem

Answer (score 0):

What type of integrated graphics care you using? You can likely get it to work no problem but will be very slow. Anyways, here's a quick guide (Skip the Nvidia card stuff if you don't have one, other steps still apply)

http://www.howtoforge.com/enabling-compiz-fusion-on-ubuntu-11.10-oneiric-ocelot