# Can not install Nvidia driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my desktop. I have three monitors, and after installing, ubuntu only detected one at 1080p. I downloaded the driver from the nvidia website, but when I stop lightdm and try to run the driver, it gives me an error message:

> ERROR: Unable to find the kernel source tree for the currently running
>   kernel.  Please make sure you have installed the kernel source files
>   for your kernel and that they are properly configured; on Red Hat
>   Linux systems, for example, be sure you have the `kernel-source` or
>   `kernel-devel` RPM installed.  If you know the correct kernel source
>   files are installed, you may specify the kernel source path with the
>   `--kernel-source-path` command line option.

I tried instead to install the driver via the terminal, with the X ppa. The installation seemed to work, but when I rebooted, my display was at 640x480 resolution, with no other options for resolution. The NVIDIA X Server settings program is there now, but when I run it, it simply tells me that I don't seem to be using their driver, and that I should run `nvidia-xconfig` as `root`. Doing so doesn't help, I simply get the same issue again. I checked the file at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, and it's an NVIDIA file (has nvidia in the header).

Does anyone know something else I can try?

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I tried installing drivers via the

> Additional Drivers

GUI utility, there were two options, one of them marked

> post-release updates

I tried both of them, in both cases it tried to download and install for a while, then said that there was an error, and that a description could be found at `/var/log/jockey.log`. Both logs were over 700 lines.