# Compiz effects aren't working properly!

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, xfce

On Ubuntu 12.04, the Compiz visual effects appears to be glitchy. I see a "window flash", after rotating the "Desktop Cube". I've used the "Magic Lamp effect" when minimizing windows, but the window content, minimizes faster, delaying the window border to minimize. "So the border and the window content gets apart, like in the picture below". I've tried updating Compiz, but no luck.
[image: Magic lamp minimizing issue]

How to fix this problem? Will Compiz work properly in XFCE? This didn't happen in Lucid Lynx. I appriciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flashing after switching workspaces is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/862430).

There seems to be only one way to get rid of it in 12.04 precise right know:

> ### WARNING
>
> Please be aware that activating this repository and downgrading to an officially unsupported version of compiz is **not recommended**. Do it only if you can't live with the flashing. You have been warned.

In a terminal, type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vanvugt/compiz-preproposed
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If you are already on the latest version of compiz, you would have to downgrade to the version from this ppa to remove the flashing (e.g. by using the "force version" option (F3) in synaptic package manager).

These packages have to be installed:

> libbamf3-0 0.2.118-0ubuntu0.1
>
> libbamf0 0.2.118-0ubuntu0.1
>
> bamfdaemon 0.2.118-0ubuntu0.1
>
> accountsservice 0.6.15-2ubuntu9
>
> libaccountsservice0 0.6.15-2ubuntu9
>
> compiz-dev 1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2
>
> compiz-plugins 1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2
>
> compiz-gnome 1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2
>
> compiz-plugins-default 1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2
>
> libdecoration0-dev 1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2
>
> libdecoration0 1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2
>
> compiz-core 1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2
>
> compiz 1:0.9.7.8-0ubuntu1vvpreproposed2
>
> devscripts 2.11.6ubuntu1.2
>
> evince 3.4.0-0ubuntu1
>
> libevince3-3 3.4.0-0ubuntu1
>
> evince-common 3.4.0-0ubuntu1
>
> libunity9 5.12.0-0ubuntu1
>
> gir1.2-unity-5.0 5.12.0-0ubuntu1
>
> python-crypto 2.4.1-1

After downgrading, these packages will have to be locked to be stopped from being upgraded to their former versions right again.

A fixed version of compiz in official repositories will probably only be available in Quantal release.

Comment: Fantastic!! Works like a charm!!!!! Thank you very much..!!!!!!! (I just logged in to the Gnome 3 session, removed all the Compiz packages, and typed all the codes in terminal, you gave me :D)

Comment: Glad it worked! :)

Comment: Hi! I think Compiz 0.9.8, the bug free version has been released... Is there a way I can insall it on Precise Pangolin?

Answer (score 0):

### For Lamp effect

I've tested Lamp *(actually magic lamp)* effect on Unity, Ubuntu 12.04. The effects is working nicely. I think, You should upgrade your `unity` and `compiz` related packages. This should fix problems.

### Desktop cube effect

You didn't mention where are using this desktop cube effect. As far as I know, "Desktop Cube" Effect is very much experimental and buggy in the Unity. If you still want to use this plugin, See this question and answer.

> [How to correctly enable Desktop Cube in Unity 3D](https://askubuntu.com/q/86977/61218)

### Compiz in XFCE

Compiz will not work *(at least without some tricksy hack!)* in XFCE, since XFCE uses another window manager called `xfwm4` as their default. But if you still want to use compiz in XFCE, [here is a link](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/07/11/run-compiz-with-xfce4/) to do that.

Comment: Sorry... it didn't work. I added a screen shot...