# I cannot find the cube option in Compiz on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, compiz, cube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to correctly enable Desktop Cube in Unity 3D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86977/how-to-correctly-enable-desktop-cube-in-unity-3d)

I have Ubuntu 12.10 and I also installed Compiz Config Settings Manager (ccsm).

When I open up ccsm and scroll down to *Desktop* **I do not find the option for Cube**. I see *Expo* and *Viewport switching* but no *Cube*.  Why is that?