# How to enable visual effects (compiz) without disabling Unity?

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, effects

How can I install compiz fusion (or whatever it is called) to have visual effects like windows burning to ash on minimize , rotating (3d cube) workspaces etc ?

I was using compiz (ccsm) in 10.10, but it does not work in 12.04.

I tried a lot of things, which mostly involved removing the sidebar (Unity ?) but it caused even more problems.

It would be great if someone posts a "stable" way to have both Unity (sidebar) and visual effects.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. : It does not have to be compiz, if there are other alternatives which work well in 12.04

Comment: Please check that you are indeed using Unity and not the fallback Unity 2D: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d  - if ccsm is not working then maybe you are not actually using Unity

Comment: Thanks! I ran `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` in the terminal and it echo'd `ubuntu` so I guess it is Unity 3D. Isn't Unity 3D the game development engine ? :S Anyway, if I'm using Unity 3D, should compiz work just fine ?

Comment: @halilpazarlama Unity 3d is a DE and a webgame engine. Also, you did install ccsm, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compiz should work by default, you may just need to install a few extra packages:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins* compizconfig-settings-manager
```

The you can search for 'compiz' in dash, then you can open 'CompizConfig Settings Manager', and use it to change the settings to what you like
[image: CCSM]

see also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86977/how-to-correctly-enable-desktop-cube-in-unity-3d).

Answer (score 0):

After installing `compiz-plugins* compizconfig-settings-manager`, please enable following wobbly windows option in effect section. you will get that animation.

[image]