# Misconfigured Compiz and lost desktop usage

Tags: unity, 14.04, compiz

I disabled something in the compiz manager, I think I disabled the openGL plugin. Now nothing is showing on my desktop, I can not interact with anything and all I can see is the background wallpaper. The bars are gone, the icons. I've tried resetting the unity, but it did not work. I reinstalled Ubuntu and it also failed. What can I do now? Help me!

Comment: Nota that most of the answers in the duplicate question are wrong. They simply do not work in 12.04+. The ones I would look apart from mine here is the one Mark Shuttleworth made and the one by user155373.

Answer (score 0):

I have left an answer in [How to correctly enable Desktop Cube in Unity 3D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86977/how-to-correctly-enable-desktop-cube-in-unity-3d) which covers several issues, but I am pretty sure this is not covered. Killing OpenGL will eventually create more problems than solutions.

In you case I would do the following:

1. Go to the terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type `ccsm`
3. Activate the OpenGL plugin. If this casues the CCSM to disappear, repeat steps 1 and 2 until you have the CCSM opened again. If not proceed to step 4.
4. Activate the unity plugin by opening the unity option and selecting the Enable option. This will cause Unity to start asking you to enable other plugins needed for it to work. Eventually after activating all of them your desktop should be back.

Comment: o terminal não abre! e eu reinstalei o ubuntu, então agora nem consigo configurar conexão a internet e não abre o terminal

Comment: Did you press the combination of keys I mentioned. You need to press them all together.

Comment: meu amigo, assim você me ofende kkkk mas já resolvi o problema, obrigado pela atenção, abraço!

Comment: @user285823 hehe big hugs friend. Happy to see you solved it ;)