# How to configure the 3d Cube compiz plug-in in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: compiz, ccsm, cube

I run Ubuntu 16.04, Unity, 64 bit and just installed `compizconfig-settings-manager`.

When I launch `ccsm`, I miss settings to configure the "3D cube" plug-in though. Where are they? Do I have to install any further packages to get them?

[image]

Comment: Please note that Ask Ubuntu is an English speaking website. Many of our members do not understand German. I translated your question for you, but please continue all further communication here in English. Thanks and welcome on our site.

Comment: Thank you ! Byte Commender! Is there a German version of ubuntu ask ?

Comment: No, there's no German Ubuntu site within the Stack Exchange network. But I know of this external forum of the German Ubuntu community: https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/ Ask Ubuntu is not related to them though.

Comment: Try installing `compiz-plugins` with `apt-get install compiz-plugins`. Then logout & login again or reboot, and see if it works. If not, see here: [How to correctly enable Desktop Cube in Unity 3D?](http://askubuntu.com/q/86977)